# A problem with Lagrangian density variation in Noether theorem derivation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, noethers-theorem, variational-calculus

I am reading a book on classical field theory and have a problem with understanding of one moment.

Let the action be $$S = \int_{\Omega} d^4x\mathcal{L}$$ and some continuous  transformation $$ \{x \rightarrow x';\:u(x) \rightarrow u'(x')\}.$$ Conventions in my book are as follows: $$u'(x) = u(x) + \bar\delta u(x),$$ so that $$\delta u(x) = u'(x') - u(x) = \bar\delta u(x) + u_{,\mu}\delta x^{\mu}.$$
Now the action is variated $$\delta S = \int_{\Omega} [(\delta d^4x)\mathcal{L} + d^4x \delta\mathcal{L}]$$

The thing I don't understand happens when the authors calculate $\delta \mathcal{L}$. They write

$$\delta \mathcal{L} = \mathcal{L}(u'(x'), \frac{\partial u'}{\partial x'}, x') - \mathcal{L}(u(x), \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}, x) = \bar\delta \mathcal{L} + \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x^{\mu}}\delta x^{\mu} ,$$ where

$$\bar\delta \mathcal{L} = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial u}\bar \delta u + \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial u_{, \nu}}\bar \delta u_{, \nu}$$

I cannot see why they use $\bar \delta u$ instead of $\delta u$. In my opinion, it shall be

$$\delta \mathcal{L} = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x^{\mu}} (x'^{\mu}-x^{\mu}) + \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial u}\bar (u'(x') - u(x)) + \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial u_{, \nu}}\bar (u'_{, \nu'} - u_{, \nu})$$

I will appreciate a lot if someone helps me to clear this thing out.

Edit 1:
Here are the pages from my book. My problem shows up on second picture just after 1.5.8 equation.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dHBg.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAqju.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPWV5.jpg

Comment: @Qmechanic Gal'tsov, Grats, Zhukovsky "Classical Fields". It is not translated into English, though.

Comment: Hi @Nick Terziev: In your last equation (v3), how is the bars supposed to act?

Comment: It turned out that it was an extremely silly question indeed: we take local (bar) variation as far as we have already taken the partial derivative by x.